# Allow different Registration forms on Symfony with FosUserBundle

Tags: php, forms, symfony, registration, fosuserbundle

I should build a website using Symfony and I need create multiple registration forms depending of user input. I know that I can create just one FormType will all different inputs and let the user select in which he is interested. But I can't do that, I should create different registration forms with different user's input in each form.
Any tip will be great.
Best regards

Comment: My experience: i also needed to customize FOSUserBundle, but i had to make lot of workarounds to make it work, i finally ended up designing my own User bundle. It is actually not difficult to go through source code of FOSUserBundle and get a grasp of how things work

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Miro I'm the guy who had an issue with the login form in Symfony (we talked at the stackoverflow's chat), after that I had another issue each time that I tried to login in, I always get "Authentication request could not be processed" message. For that I decided used FosUserBundle. I'm new at Symfony but I'm investing time to understand how work with it. If I want do it through multiple logins, to show them depeding of situation, should I rewrite the registerAction from FosUserBundle's Controller?

Comment: yes, if you want different registration forms, then you need to do changes in controller of registration action

Comment: Okay, perfect thanks